# How can I publish an accepted IEEE Paper after the conference and before official publication?

Tags: copyright, ieee, preprint

I would like to publish my accepted and presented IEEE paper, since the proceedings probably will be published next year. I did not publish any preprint (since I just finished at conference deadline :-)) How do I do this? As far as I understand their policy, this is not possible. Is this right?

The terms state the following:
*"Personal Servers. Authors and/or their employers shall have the right to post the accepted version of IEEE-copyrighted articles on their own personal servers or the servers of their institutions or employers without permission from IEEE, provided that the posted version includes a prominently displayed IEEE copyright notice and, when published, a full citation to the original IEEE publication, including a link to the article abstract in IEEE Xplore. Authors shall not post the final, published versions of their papers."*

As I understand it correctly, I can use the CRC version that I submitted and add the "IEEE copyright notice" to it for posting it on my personal website of my university?! Is there any definition what the "prominently displayed IEEE copyright notice" means and how do I add it? How do you add it?

Or do I need an earlier version than the Camera Ready Copy (CRC), e.g. the previously submitted one?

After the proceedings are published, I add a link to the published version, right?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ask IEEE. Seems doubtful, though. Who has copyright? If they do, do you have a license?

Comment: IEEE allows for this as long you have a boiler plate or the version you are posting is different to the accepted version.  I post all my conference papers on my web page.

Comment: @VitaminE: what do you mean with boilerplate? With different: do you mean with different? How much different?

Comment: What is CRC? Cyclic Redundancy Check?

Comment: @VitaminE Camera Ready Copy ...

Comment: @VitaminE I added some information in the original description. Can you help further, please?

Answer (score 1):

**Accepted Version is defined by IEEE as follows:**
"An accepted article is a version which has been revised by the author to incorporate review suggestions, and which has been accepted by IEEE for publication."

> **What other steps are necessary for authors who would like to post their accepted articles?**  The following copyright notice must be
> displayed on the initial screen displaying IEEE copyrighted material:
>
> *© 20xx IEEE. Personal use of this material is permitted. Permission from IEEE must be obtained for all other uses, in any current or
> future media, including  reprinting/republishing this material for
> advertising or promotional purposes, creating new collective works,
> for resale or redistribution to servers or lists, or reuse of any
> copyrighted component of this work in other works.*
>
> Upon publication, authors are asked to include either a link to the
> abstract of the published  article in IEEE Xplore®, or the article’s
> Digital Object Identifier (DOI).

Information taken from [FAQ on Authors' Posting of Accepted IEEE
Papers](https://www.ieee.org/content/dam/ieee-org/ieee/web/org/pubs/author_version_faq.pdf) from
[here](https://www.ieee.org/publications/rights/author-posting-policy.html).